# Getting json data from php ( or array?)

Tags: php, json, server

I need to get the JSON data from here https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/info/play.mineverge.net

I need the "online": 126 to display in my web page.

```
"players": {
    "online": 126,
    "max": 500
```

here is my current code that (not working) to get the JSON. Am I doing something wrong? It displays everything not just "online":

```
             $playeronline = file_get_contents ('https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/info/' . $server); 
            echo $playeronline->players[1]; 
            echo $playeronline['online'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, and I tested it:

```
$str = file_get_contents ('https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/info/play.mineverge.net');

$playersonline = json_decode( $str );

echo $playersonline->players->online;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ,

```
$playeronline = file_get_contents ('https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/info/' . $server); 
$data=json_decode($playeronline,true);

echo $data['players']['online'];
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) you need to use the `json_decode` function as follows:

```
$playeronline = file_get_contents('https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/info/' . $server); 

$obj = json_decode($playeronline );
echo $playersonline->players->online;
```